# Volume of a prism

Tags: solid-geometry

Right rectangular prism has a base with diagonal *a* and a lateral face with diagonal *b*. Find the volume of the prism.

Comment: I think you are misstating the question.  The volume is determined by three variables and you have two. Although $a$ is determined by the two variables width and length and $b$ is determined by the two variables height and length, If we fix $a$ and $b$ width and height will vary as length varies and volume = height x width x length will vary as length varies.  Were you told anything about the *second* lateral face?  That would fix a third variable.

Comment: No... that's all. It says *a lateral face with diagonal b*...

Comment: Then you simply to not have enough information.  Period.

Comment: $$l^2 = a^2 + a^2 = 2a^2$$
$$V=\dfrac{a^2}{4}\sqrt{4b^2-l^2}$$
$$(2b)^2=h^2+l^2$$
$$V=\dfrac{a^2h}{4} = (\dfrac{a}{2})^2\cdot h$$

tried to backward solve it.

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information to answer the question.  Consider two prisms with $2 \times 3$ bases, one with height $2$ and one with height $3$.  The diagonal of the base is $\sqrt{13}$.  The diagonal of the lateral face on the $3$ side of the first and the diagonal of the lateral face on the $2$ side of the second is also $\sqrt {13}$ but the volume of the first is $12$ and the second $18$.

Answer (score 0):

Let the dimensions be $h,w, l$.  The base diagonal $a=\sqrt{w^2 + l^2}$ and the lateral diagonal $b =\sqrt{h^2 + l^2}$.  And the volume is $hwl$.

So $w = \sqrt{a^2 - l^2}$ and $h= \sqrt{b^2 - l^2}$ and Volume = $hwl = l\sqrt{(a-l)(a+l)(b-l)(b+l)}$

If $a,b$ are constants, then other than $0 < l < \min(a,b)$, $l$ is indeterminable.  The volume may vary as $l$ varies.

Comment: Hmmm..., I dont know. We have to express the volume only with *a* and *b*. The answer is $\frac{a^2}{4}\sqrt{2(2b^2-a^2)}$

Comment: "We have to express the volume only with a and b."  I know.  But that was my point.  You *can't*. "The answer is $\frac{a^2}{4}\sqrt{2(2b^2-a^2)}$.  That is true for one value of $l$. If $d^2 = a^2+h^2=w^2 + b^2$ then $d^2 = a^2 + b^2 + l^2$ but you need to put this in terms of $d$.  It sounds like the question stated something about $d$ that you are leaving out.

Comment: Suppose $w=3, l= 4$ and $h = 3$ then $a = b = 5$ and $V = 3*4*3 = 36$.  But suppose $l=3, w=4, h= 4$  then $a=b=5$ but $V = 3*4*4=48$.

Comment: I think the question was supposed to be that the prism has *two* lateral faces with diagonals $b$.   That will force the base to be a square.  As the question is stated *now* the prism has *one* lateral face with diagonal $b$ and could have *another* lateral face with a different diagonal.  So the question does not have enough information.  But.....

Comment: If the prism has *two* congruent lateral faces then the base is a square.  And $w = l = \sqrt{\frac 12}a$ and $h= \sqrt{b^2 - \frac {a^2}2}$ and volume = $wlh = \frac a2\sqrt{b^2 - \frac {a^2}2}$

Comment: Yes... I got it, but... why is this question in my book with no any other given elements and with  a fixed anwser.

Comment: are you sure the question did not state that the prism has *two* lateral faces?  If so, then your stated answer has a typo but the answer would be $\frac a4\sqrt{2(2b^2 - a^2)}$.  ANyway textbooks *often* have errors.

Comment: well it has 4 lateral faces

Comment: "well it has 4 lateral faces"  yes, but the opposite faces are congruent.  So there are are two, bottom and top, with diagonal $a$, two, front and back lateral, with diameter $b$ and two, left and right lateral, with diagonal $c$.  As $a^2 = w^2 + l^2;b^2 = l^2 + h^2;c^2=w^2+h^2$ we get volume = $lwh=\sqrt{\frac{(a^2+b^2-c^2)(a^2+c^2-b^2)(b^2+c^2-a^2)}8}$.  But that requires all 3 diagonals.  but if have some relation between $b$ and $c$ ....